Incrementing LET variable by 1 each time If statement is false, loop IF statement until true
I am trying to make a dynamic book index that lists the chapter that a specified page is in. I have a table with the chapter in one column. In the other column, a user should input the last page # in that chapter:



Chapter
Last Page #




Ch.2
4


Ch.3
5


Ch.4
8



I have another table with numbers from 1-10 pre-filled in one column. The second column should auto-populate with the chapter that that page corresponds to:



Page #
Chapter




1
Ch.2


2
Ch.2


3
Ch.2


4
Ch.2


5
Ch.3


6
Ch.4


7
Ch.4


8
Ch.4


9




When the Page # in the second table goes beyond the final page of the final chapter, the Chapter column should remain blank.
I decided to try using a recursive If-statement to accomplish this, running through the statement until it returns TRUE:
=LET(y,2,chap_name,"Ch." & y,if1,IF(A21<=XLOOKUP(chap_name,$E$7:$E$20,$F$7:$F$20),chap_name,y=y+1),IF(if1=FALSE,if1))

The formula didn't work. I have 2 questions:

Is this type of recursive statement possible in Excel? If so, what did I do wrong?
Is there an alternative solution to this problem?


why not something like this : =XLOOKUP(Page#Array, E7:E20,F7:F20,"",1)? if you are trying to return the Chapters?

Would I just use that code on its own, or insert it into the larger formula (in the first IF-statement)? And yes, the syntax may be incorrect. Thanks!

No syntax is ok, short sighted sorry. no just enter the formula in the output sheet. your larger formula is not required since you are trying to return the chapters based on the page#. so XLOOUP() with exact match or larger should work.

Hm, this seems to be returning 0 for all cells. Here's the formula I used: =XLOOKUP(A21:A221,$H$4:$H$17,$I$4:$I$17,"",1). A21:A221 is the Page # Array. Thanks for the help though!

Here is what you could try using the XLOOKUP() function:


=XLOOKUP(D2:D16,B2:B4,A2:A4,"",1)



@Ecsizemore no issues at all, even I was confused in the beginning, had to re-read your post, why you were using a longer path. Realized it will be simple with XLOOKUP(). have a great day ahead bye
